# How to Increment NVarchar Value in While Loop Using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to increment nvarchar value of a variable like this;

```
    declare @i int
    set @i = 0
    -- I want a book `@BookSerialNo`  to be increment like e.g abcde-1, abcde-2 
    set @BookSerialNo = CAST(@BookSerialNo +'-' + @i as nvarchar(50));
    WHILE(@i<>@Quantity)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Library.BookDetail
            (
                BookId,
                BookSerialNo,
                CreatedBy,
                CreateDate,
                UpdateDate,
                Updateby
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @BookId,
                @BookSerialNo,
                @CreatedBy,
                @CreatedDate,
                @UpdatedDate,
                @UpdatedBy
            )
            SET @i = @i+1;
        END
```

So, My question is, 
**How to Increment the value of `@BookSerialNo` eache time int the loop?**

I want it like e.g 'abcdef-1', 'abcdef-2', 'abcdef-3', I just want to include the numbers after the '-'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this..

```
    set @BookSerialNo = @BookSerialNo +'-0';
    WHILE(@i<>@Quantity)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Library.BookDetail
            (
                BookId,
                BookSerialNo,
                CreatedBy,
                CreateDate,
                UpdateDate,
                Updateby
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @BookId,
                @BookSerialNo,
                @CreatedBy,
                @CreatedDate,
                @UpdatedDate,
                @UpdatedBy
            )
            SET @i = @i+1;
            --increment the serialno also
            SET @BookSerialNo = SUBSTRING(@BookSerialNo, 0, CHARINDEX('-',@BookSerialNo)+1);  
            set @BookSerialNo = @BookSerialNo + CAST (@i as nvarchar(50));
        END
```

Comment: you have to use SubString function avoid the repeation of '-' character also.

Answer (score 4):

Just move the `set` inside the `while` ?

```
WHILE(@i<>@Quantity)
    BEGIN
    set @BookSerialNo = cast(@BookSerialNo as nvarchar(50)) +'-' + 
                        cast(@i as nvarchar(50));
    ....
    SET @i = @i+1;
    END
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1234234-0-' to data type int.

Comment: Try to `cast` the `integer` to `nvarchar`, answer edited.  If `@BookSerialNo` is an `nvarchar`, you can of course omit the first `cast`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @BookSerialNo datatype is nvarchar

```
Try this

WHILE(@i<>@Quantity)
BEGIN
    set @BookSerialNo = @BookSerialNo +'-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@i);
    ....
    SET @i = @i+1;
END
```